# pyspark failing to create dataframe with 1000000+ rows

Tags: memory-leaks, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file of size ~38 mb, with 1017210 rows and 10 columns. I am using spark in standalone mode with a 64-bit windows OS and 8 GB of RAM. I am trying to read that csv into pyspark dataframe. First I have loaded the data as :

```
    trainRaw = sc.textFile("D:/Rossmann/train/train.csv").map(lambda line:line.split(","))
```

Then I am trying to read to a dataframe as:

```
    trainRaw_df = trainRaw.toDF(["Store","DayOfWeek","Date","Sales","Customers","Open","Promo","StateHoliday","SchoolHoliday"]).first()
```

But, I am getting error as:

```
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 12 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) with 1 output partitions
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 12 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393)
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 12 (PythonRDD[38] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43)
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_19 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.2 KB
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_19_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.3 KB
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_19_piece0 in memory on localhost:49516 (size: 3.3 KB
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 19 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 12 (PythonRDD[38] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43)
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 12.0 with 1 tasks
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 14
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 14)
    16/08/17 10:27:41 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/D:/Rossmann/train/train.csv:0+19028976
    16/08/17 10:27:42 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 1328
    16/08/17 10:27:42 ERROR PythonRunner: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
            at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
            at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:622)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:442)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)
    16/08/17 10:27:42 ERROR PythonRunner: This may have been caused by a prior exception:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
            at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
            at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:622)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:442)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)
    16/08/17 10:27:42 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 14)
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
            at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
            at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:622)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:442)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)
    16/08/17 10:27:42 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 14
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
            at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
            at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:622)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:442)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)

    16/08/17 10:27:42 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
    16/08/17 10:27:42 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 12.0
    16/08/17 10:27:42 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 12
    16/08/17 10:27:42 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 12 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) failed in 1.454 s
    16/08/17 10:27:42 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 12 failed: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>"
      File "D:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py"
        rs = self.take(1)
      File "D:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py"
        res = self.context.runJob(self
      File "D:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\context.py"
        port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc()
      File "D:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py"
      File "D:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py"
        return f(*a
      File "D:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py"
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 1 times
    ): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
            at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
            at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:622)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:442)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)

    Driver stacktrace:
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
            at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
            at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:393)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
            at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
            at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:622)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:442)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)

    >>> 16/08/17 10:32:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_17_piece0 on localhost:49516 in memory (size: 3.3 KB
    16/08/17 10:32:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_19_piece0 on localhost:49516 in memory (size: 3.3 KB
    16/08/17 10:32:03 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 14
    16/08/17 10:32:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_18_piece0 on localhost:49516 in memory (size: 6.1 KB
    16/08/17 10:32:03 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 13
    16/08/17 10:32:03 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 12
    16/08/17 10:32:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_16_piece0 on localhost:49516 in memory (size: 3.7 KB
    16/08/17 10:32:03 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 11
    16/08/17 10:32:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_14_piece0 on localhost:49516 in memory (size: 3.7 KB
    16/08/17 10:32:03 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 10
```

I have increased the worker memory and changed the JAVA_OPTS as below:

```
    export  SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1
    export  SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
    export  SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=6g"
    export  SPARK_MEM=6g"
    export  SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=6g"
    export  SPARK_JAVA_OPTS=""-Dspark.executor.memory=6g -Dspark.storage.memoryFraction=0.66 -Dspark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer -Dspark.executor.memory=6g -Dspark.locality.wait=60000000"
    export  JAVA_OPTS=""-Xms6G -Xmx6G"""
```

But nothing helped as such. Please suggest how can I handle this type of memory issues.

Comment: It looks like you did not post the first error, there should be another one earlier on the logs.

Comment: Does `trainRaw.first()` work?

Answer (score 0):

Does trainRaw.show() fail as well ? If not, try passing a proper schema with types it should make it easier

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([StructField('art_Store', StringType(), True),
...
print trainRaw.toDF(schema).first()
```